# Grails application deployment fails on the Tomcat server

Tags: grails, tomcat7

I am deploying the grails application on the tomcat server,I have tried so many things but I'm still unable to resolve the issue,I have  following exception in tomcat logs.

```
o

v 08, 2017 9:05:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing AtmosphereFramework
Nov 08, 2017 9:05:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Nov 08, 2017 9:05:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 08, 2017 9:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
    at Config.run(Config.groovy:184)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: I'm going to guess, based on _reading your error messages for you_, that `Cannot run program "git": error=13, Permission denied` is the problem - looks like it's failing to call Git from your Config.groovy

Comment: @BurtBeckwith thanks for your reply, your are right. There was git call in config.groovy, I removed that, it's working now thanks.